# auto delete rows according to a date field using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I have a table with a field `end date`.
I would like that all rows that contain a record in the `end date` field get deleted when the date is passed.

Once I have the right msyql syntax/command, I can make a cron job from it.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried? Also, note that MySQL now also supports events.

Comment: how often are you inserting or updating values? because you can also make it with a trigger

Comment: please give us some code, here is nothing for us to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or something like this:

```
DELETE FROM db_table WHERE end_date<NOW() AND end_date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: or CURDATE() instead of NOW(), depending on what you save

Comment: where are you getting this?

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM table WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL

end_date field must be null for those records that should not be deleted.

Comment: "when the date is passed."

Comment: ^^ what does that mean

Comment: That means your answer is incorrect. He doesn't want to delete all records with an end date, but all records with an end date which has passed.